# 12 V vehicle bulb voltage monitoring - prevent flashing LEDs (potential circuit design?)

Tags: led, capacitor, filter, automotive

I have a digital dash in my car (Haltech IC7) which has inputs for lights so that it can display indicators etc. on the digital dash. I've tried coding out voltage monitoring but it doesn't seem to have worked for the indicators.

This results in my digital dash indicators "flickering". Is there some kind of little circuit I can make that would filter this out? Something with a capacitor maybe? I have no idea what I would need to do, but I'm thinking something that could take the input signal, and "smooth" or "filter" it so that the voltage monitoring pulses are ignored so that the output side is a consistent on/off for the indicator duration rather than the random flickering when it decides to check for voltage/bulb out. Is this even feasible?

Comment: Just to clarify - it's the monitoring pulses from the car's ECU which are checking for broken bulbs or whatever which you want to filter out of the signal which gets sent to the dashcam? Do you have any way to measure the width or amplitude of these pulses?

Comment: @brhans it's a digital dash, so it replaces the instrument cluster, not a dashcam :) - but you're correct about the ECU pulsing checking for broken bulbs yes.  I have a multimeter or pocket oscilloscope - would I just connect these to the indicator +ve and -ve or something?

Comment: What signal do you have for a working light and what for a defect light and what kind of signal do you need for the dash instruments? Did you try a simple R/C lowpass filter 10 k / 100 uF?

Comment: @Jens I don't know enough about it which is what prompted me to ask. So far as I understand, on my 2003 BMW, the Bulbs are all halogen (Headlights are Xenon however, but indicators, tail lights, side lights etc are halogen).  Some ECU "pulses" the bulbs by turning then on and off in super quick succession as some kind of voltage monitoring.  Since the bulbs are Halogen, this is not noticeable, it happens so fast it has no affect on the halogen bulbs.  However, LEDs "flicker", and so does the input "signal" (a +12v supply from the bulb) into the digital dash causing dash lights to also flicker

Comment: For how many light signals do you want to add this feature?

Comment: @Jens Currently just 2 signals (left and right indicator) that goes into the digital dash, although I'd be interested if there was something was able to connect "in-line" so to speak if using a voltage monitored signal for any reason externally (I have a diff project that uses an Arduino and I "filtered" out the voltage pulses (from memory) by simply ignoring on/off pulses within 100ms using a counter kinda thing (Eg, if the signal went off/on 10 times within 100ms ignore it)

Comment: Yes, a capacitor would likely work. But more information is needed about the source, load, and sensor. I suppose an equivalent circuit from the ECU is too much to ask for, but what about the dash / instrument system? Also, is this proprietary, or open source? Can it not simply be modified to filter out glitches in software (as should've been done in the first place!)?

Comment: @TimWilliams The Haltech Digital Dash is closed source - although I suppose I could email them with my issue and see what they say... maybe there's hidden setting I'm not aware of.

Excuse my ignorance now, but is half that stuff needed? ECU circuit is unlikely to be found.  I presume the load is different depending on what bulb is being tested, I've no idea how to check! I do know I used a 50W load resistor when I customised my indicators to fancy rgb led halo things. I don't there's a sensor, I assumed it a was pulse sent and received by ecu via a module I guess.

Comment: I actually think I don't know enough about what the vehicle is actually doing in order to be able to provide enough information so think I'll have to abandon this question (or delete it)

Comment: Yeah, may be one of those things that needs an experienced eye, in person, to figure out. The thing is, just throwing in a capacitor, or RC or whatever, may work -- but we can't say for certain what value is needed, and whether it might cause problems elsewhere. And the best way to determine that, is to fill in those blanks.